# Water hammer for all faucets

Tags: plumbing

This issue I am having is little different than " How do I fix "water hammer" problem asked a few years ago.

1    The problem I am having started a month ago after living in this house for 10 years with no problem.

2    All faucets during shut off create a thud sound.

3    The sound comes from a single location somewhere upstairs either in the wall or attic

4    If I turn off the faucets slowly, I do not get it.

5    Both hot and cold faucets create the sound

6    My incoming city water pressure is 75 psi

7    I tried to shut off all water, drain pipes and restart but it did not work

8    No noise for Toilets or Washing Machines or showers surprisingly. Only all faucets.

9    Putting hammer arresters on every faucet is impractical, right?

Need help. Thanks

Comment: Mini-Rester Water Hammer Arrestor

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be hammer arresters, and it's not that difficult. Or just go back to 'traditional' taps (2-commands 'screw like'). I suggest you to reduce water pressure to about 3bar (about 45 PSI) to preserve piping and reduce hammer effect.

If you have a 'single water entry' to each bathroom, you can install an hammer arrester there, so it protects all the faucets after.

Comment: I agree with @DDS that water pressure for residential is very high it is normally in the 45PSI range. Arrestors or not your pipes are going to take a beating, add a regulator to the incoming water supply.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like installing hammer arrestors they have a tendency to leak even when installed correctly and they only last for a year. Trying lowering your water pressure to <50 psi and make sure that the valves connecting to the faucet are fully open; if you look underneath the sink you will see the valves.